# Is this a correct way to use "although"?

Tags: word-choice

> Generally, organized religion is a force of stability within a culture. People who share a religion have something important in common, and ***although*** strangers are less likely to murder each other. It can also be quite divisive as well

Here, I've never seen the word used like that before. Shouldn't it be rephrased like as follows?

"~and although strangers they maybe, they are less likely~"

But said paragraph is from what was apparently written by a native speaker, so I'm not confident at all. Is that considered a good writing? And if that kind of usage is possible, could it be alright to say like "Although losers are likely to get the prizes" which conveys "Although they lost, they can still get the prizes"?

Comment: It's good English, but I would add a comma after 'strangers'. Jim and Bob, although brothers, support different soccer teams.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Oh now I get it. It was "People, although strangers, are less likely..".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine English. The parse would be more obvious with extra words, but those words are generally not necessary:

> People who share a religion have something important in common, and although **they are**<sup>[1]</sup> strangers **they** are less likely to murder each other.

It would actually come across much clearer spoken aloud, as the sentence structure would be apparent due to emphasis and tiny pauses.

---

[1]: *are* might also be replaced with *may be*